# JTwig global field filter

Tags: jtwig

I have to escape all string fields of a JTwig template.
For field I mean each: `{{myfield}}` or `{{myobject.myproperty}}`

I know I can use a filter like `{{myfield|escape}}`, but this escape should be used for ALL fields so I would like to know if is there a method to use or to override to do a global filter for each string field.

For example:

```
public String function filter(String input){
   return input.replaceAll("[^\\x00-\\x7F]", "");
}
```

(I'm not using Jtwig as html template engine but for a general template engine for raw text printing. This is the reason to escape non-ascii chars).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking to define an escape mode by default. In Jtwig there is two ways of achieving this.

1. Defining a custom escape mode and use autoescape tag to wrap the entire template.

```java
EnvironmentConfiguration configuration = configuration()
  .escape()
    .engines()
      .add("Custom", removeStrangeCharacters())
    .and()
  .and()
.build();
```

```
{% autoescape 'Custom' %}{{ myField }}{% endautoescape %}
```

2. Defining a custom escape mode and setting it as the initial escape mode in Jtwig configuration.

```java
EnvironmentConfiguration configuration = configuration()
  .escape()
    .withInitialEngine("Custom")
    .engines()
      .add("Custom", removeStrangeCharacters())
    .and()
  .and()
.build();
```

```
{{ myField }}
```

You can find both examples working in [here](https://github.com/jtwig/jtwig-core/blob/master/src/test/java/org/jtwig/integration/stackoverflow/JtwigGlobalFieldFilterTest.java).

Comment: Seems exactly what I need!  Thank you so much

Comment: Now I'm using JtwigConfiguration object, is it replaced by EnvironmentConfiguration?

Comment: The solution pointed out only works with jtwig 5.x. JtwigConfiguration only exists in 3.x and 4.x.